# How to send query parameters and headers from ApiGateway to SQS using CloudFormation

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

In general, I want to run `Lambda Function` asynchronously. To do so, I configured `API Gateway`, `SQS` and `Lambda` according to the [API GATEWAY INTEGRATION WITH SQS VIA CLOUDFORMATION](https://www.matthealy.com.au/blog/post/api-gateway-sqs-integration-cloudformation/). It works fine and `Lambda` (written in `Java`) received following `SQSEvent`:

```json
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "551083bc-a15c-4957-904b-71d6689bc87d",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBtPo2WzDrTWCXXWFjYZeycQaAsQuW9TlfGHTWO/btf2O791lY9dCQ63/VVpJrGxXbe+UL/sJXFflQdb7XRRqYSj4L/+igSbkk2r7vpaPkWIIibiW7ibKG6QKiryQ8b/GHEm2cA+DnMj2uZFu2KBz6LUHqAWMBDSq0f8E8EAsLLFeshttP5O1dWuplQQ9vDRb5t96F/+1zzGCFudyefwsHD8yJLKWs+NmhK/hav3/VlCM/KwKCJnnOJKXL69WA68a1uvl4gRHAQcGtDim+hQz7bo6cEowAeCC9Yuu7avnvMvY0Swzoee+2NP52vxJ/lcFA7XEvUGQvKfmSD1yrGbl1k0KNeGquhSQJ9g3GOfZhA4U1KRVjriudDcEXSqTBi3uBkAsUNnblvN4UTVsRsie2//z53kRtl2s+xm1UQuOyYWk=",
            "body": "{\n    \"key\":\"val\"\n}",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "AWSTraceHeader": "Root=1-619fe85e-4586d2b66df708be2f63b670",
                "SentTimestamp": "1637869662813",
                "SenderId": "AROARCTTKJ5X3PLJM5UWI:BackplaneAssumeRoleSession",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1637869662817"
            },
            "md5OfBody": "5d30b64dec540a25aafe61a756a0a3c0",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:arst-uat-CreateStudyDefineTranslation",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see `body` here, which I send to `API Gateway`. **My question is:** How provide request's headers and query parameters to the `SQSEvent`? I.e. when I send a request to the `API Gateway`, I want to have access to its `query parameters` and `header` within `Lambda`.
This is a relevant part of my `CloudFormation` script:

```yaml
CreateQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub '${Project}-${Environment}-CreateQueue'

PostCreate:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      ResourceId: !Ref RootResourceId
      RestApiId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub '${Project}-${Environment}-RestApiId'
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          StatusCode: 202
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 202
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.header.Content-Type: '''application/x-www-form-urlencoded'''
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: 'Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body'
        Credentials:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub '${Project}-${Environment}-ApiGatewayRoleArn'
        Uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sqs:path/${AWS::AccountId}/${CreateQueue.QueueName}'
```

Comment: I might be wrong but have you tried API GW body mapping templates?

Comment: I do not follow you. Could you give an example?

Comment: I was referring to this but not sure it's will help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html

Comment: One more thing if you have a custom authorizer Lambda to authenticate your request there you can append the API request headers to the message body as part of auth response,